# How to make bootstrap progress bar text independent to the colored part?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

Using the bootstrap [progressbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp), as you can see in the images inside the link, the text inside the bar moves with the width of the colored part.

Is there a way to change this setting such that the text could be centered in regards to the whole horizontal bar (colored and white colored part altogether)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```js
var progressBarText = $('.progress-bar').html();

$('.progress-bar').html('');

$('.progress').append('<div class="progress-bar-text">' + progressBarText + '</div>');
```

```css
.progress {
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Progress Bar With Label</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:30%">
      30%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) that was easy but somehow did not reach my mind.

Comment: You're welcome  I tried to figure it out with css only, but that didn't work, seems we have to write some scripts.